# SQL CASE statement, one result seems unreachable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, case

I'm trying to puzzle through a large set of database stored procedures I'm now maintaining, and I've come to a piece that is confusing. I can't tell if it contains redundant/useless code, or if I'm missing some nuance to it, as I'm still only intermediate at the SQL language.  Here's the section of code in question:

```
UPDATE #NewValues
SET ValidNumber = CASE WHEN SP.ModelNumber IS NULL THEN 0
                            ELSE 1
                        END
FROM #NewValues NV
LEFT OUTER JOIN Stage.Products SP
    ON NV.SKU = SP.SKU
    AND (NV.ModelNumber = SP.ModelNumber OR NV.UPC = SP.ModelNumber)
WHERE NV.SKU IN (
    SELECT NV.SKU
    FROM #NewValues NV
    INNER JOIN Stage.Products SP
        ON NV.SKU = SP.SKU
        AND (NV.ModelNumber = SP.ModelNumber OR NV.UPC = SP.ModelNumber)
    WHERE NV.ValidNumber = 1
)
```

From working through this, it seems to me as though there is no case in which `SP.ModelNumber` will be NULL, as the nested `SELECT` statement will never return SKUs with `SP.ModelNumber` NULL results. So the only thing that can ever do is `SET ValidNumber = 1`. Is that correct?  Again, I'm not sure if there is something else going on here that I'm not able to factor into the logic, but it seems as though the nested `SELECT` statement would be all you would need to use to achieve the same results. Because of the way this code is positioned in a much larger query, I'm having an extremely difficult time trying to set up a situation that would match normal use to test this, especially since I'm not sure what the `ValidNumber` values would be *before* this section of code runs.

Comment: This is what we called the "Idiot proof". You may be surprised how people would enter the data in the most unexpected way. As a backend developer, we have to take into consideration ALL kind of possible stupid ways (with no offense) people will enter the data.

Just a side joke: Have you ever seen a warning label on a hair dryer saying: Do not use this in the shower?

Comment: just because at least one of the sku's has a vaild modelNumber does not mean that all of those sku's have valid modelNumbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the data.  If a single `Sku` can have multiple records in the newvalues table, then the `outer join` might be needed and it could be possible to set `validnumber = 0`.

---

Here's some sample data to try to illustrate (fiddle below):

```
create table newvalues (validnumber int, sku int, modelnumber int, upc int);
create table products (sku int, modelnumber int);

insert into newvalues values (1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 1), (null, 1, 2, 2);
insert into products values (1, 1);
```

As you can see, there are multiple results in the newvalues table with `sku = 1`.

---

And then the `update` statement:

```
UPDATE NewValues
SET validnumber = CASE WHEN SP.ModelNumber IS NULL THEN 0
                            ELSE 1
                        END
FROM NewValues NV
LEFT OUTER JOIN Products SP
    ON NV.SKU = SP.SKU
    AND (NV.ModelNumber = SP.ModelNumber OR NV.UPC = SP.ModelNumber)
WHERE NV.SKU IN (
    SELECT NV.SKU
    FROM NewValues NV
    INNER JOIN Products SP
        ON NV.SKU = SP.SKU
        AND (NV.ModelNumber = SP.ModelNumber OR NV.UPC = SP.ModelNumber)
    WHERE NV.ValidNumber = 1
);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c91f/1)

This updates all rows, some to 0 and some to 1, because at least one of those existed in the subquery with the `inner join`.  This will not negate the `outer join` as multiple rows exist for the same `sku`, so they all get updated (even those where `sp.modelnumber is null`)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I figured I was missing an aspect of how the data already in the tables could be structured.  One note: I had to use `insert into newvalues select (1, 1, 1, 1) union all select (0, 1, 1, 1) union all select (null, 1, 2, 2)` to get multiple rows inserted. I guess that's a change for later versions of SQL server? I'm using 2005.

Answer (score 0):

The original coder is just being safe.
There is a possibility that there could be an item in #NewValues which does not exist in Stage.Products, and if that is the case the LEFT JOIN will cause all fields in SP to be NULL where there is no match.

Comment: Yes, but you remove the `NULL` values in the `where` clause?

Comment: it is an update, so what if it was valid, and no longer is, because it was deleted?

Comment: Except that those are also eliminated by the where clause because the where clause query uses an inner join on identical criteria, which will ensure that any SKU where the left join would produce a null SP.ModelNumber would be eliminated by the where in with an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but for what do you use the first `WHERE` ?

```
WHERE NV.SKU IN (
    SELECT NV.SKU
    FROM #NewValues NV
    INNER JOIN Stage.Products SP
        ON NV.SKU = SP.SKU
        AND (NV.ModelNumber = SP.ModelNumber OR NV.UPC = SP.ModelNumber)
    WHERE NV.ValidNumber = 1
)
```

You are doing the same `JOIN` here like in the upper one.

I would go for:

```
UPDATE #NewValues
SET ValidNumber = CASE WHEN SP.ModelNumber IS NULL THEN 0
                        ELSE 1
                    END
FROM #NewValues NV
INNER JOIN Stage.Products SP
    ON NV.SKU = SP.SKU
    AND (NV.ModelNumber = SP.ModelNumber OR NV.UPC = SP.ModelNumber)
WHERE NV.ValidNumber = 1
```